# Breaking up a dataframe column into two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently having a problem where I am splitting a column into two separate columns. When I perform my code it runs without any errors, but the dataframe is still the same. I'm not sure where my mistake is.

```
url = 'https://www.teamrankings.com/nba/player/clint-capela/game-log'
html = requests.get(url).content
get_log = pd.read_html(html)
players_log = get_log[0]

game_log = players_log.head()
players_log.info()

players_log.join(players_log['FGM-FGA'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'A', 1:'B'}))
players_log.info()
print(game_log)
```

Comment: You need to reassign players_long, join is not a inplace operation.  IE... `players_log = players_logs.join(....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas operations by default doesn't change the original dataframe and returns a new object, so

```py
players_log = players_log.join(players_log['FGM-FGA'].str.split('-', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'A', 1:'B'}))
```

should do it